# Add linebreak after specific character in jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string, for example

```
var string = 'This is my string. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.'.
```

This text, however, may be different.
My question is how, using JavaScript/jQuery, could I make a new line after every dot in this string so that each sentence starts in a new line ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: wow, no effort made, and three answers so far

Answer (score 1):

```
string.split(".").join(".\n")
```

Probably.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```js
var string = 'This is my string. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.'
console.log(string.replace(/\./g, '.\n'))
```

Comment: @Stphane can you elaborate your statement?

Comment: You replace the dot instead of just adding a newline.

Comment: @Stphane: The thing about the escapes is not true for JS.

Comment: I dont want to delete dots, just make linebreak after dot.

Comment: @Pat can you see carefully?

Comment: @H.B. You are right, I've been confusing with other languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'This is my string. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.';
string.split(".").join("<br>");
```

this what you mean ?